# Bootstrap: fa-icons go above the header in sm layout (smartphone view)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having problems with a Bootstap template I'm not able to fix:
When the page is viewed by a smartphone (sm layout) my fa-icons (I have 3 of them in the page) go above the header.

All the other items work properly, and I can't find a good suggestion to fix it: is there a propery to set? How is it managed?

Here you can see an example taken from etreviso.it:
http://www.etreviso.it/images/3viso.jpg

This is the code used to insert the icons:

```html
          <div class="col-md-4"> <span class="fa-stack fa-5x"> <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i> 
            <i class="fa fa-cutlery fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i> </span> </div>
```

cal-md-4 is defined as container in a css file.
fa-items are taken from Awsome font.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Alessio

Comment: maybe a jsfiddle or at least some code could help...^^

Comment: The question as it is is not appropriate for Stack Overflow. have you worked on any code that you can show here?

Comment: I see, you are right: I'm editing the original post to add the code.

Comment: Truthfully, adding in the code you have does not give the same results as what you are showing.  If you want any help, you are going to have to provide more code.